# Bootstrap dropdown select long content is floating out of browser explorer and firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a a right panel that contains dropdown list (html select element). Some of my list items are long. So I can not see on Firefox and Explorer browser. This is [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/99vonou3/1/).

```
<div class="rightPanel">
    <div class="rightPanelContent">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-body"> 
              <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <option>This is small content</option>
                    <option>This is  a very very very large content</option>
                    <option>This is medium</option>                    
                  </select>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is css code:

```
.rightPanel{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
.rightPanelContent{
    width:250px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

I used bootstrap dropdown classes but same result.

**Explorer and Firefox view.**

[image]

**Chrome view**

[image]

Comment: make content smaller or select box width larger

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use [bootstrap button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) instead of `<select>`, so that we can have more control over the size and everything